# Custom Post Type post ordering not working

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I'm having a problem with entries for a custom post type not being ordered as expected inside a custom query:

```
<h4>Related projects</h4>

            <?php

                $rp_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'work',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        );


                $related_projects = new WP_Query($rp_args);
            ?>

            <ul>
                <?php 
                if($related_projects->have_posts()):
                while ($related_projects->have_posts()) : $related_projects->the_post();
            ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
            <?php
               endwhile;
               endif;
            ?>
            </ul>
```

It's supposed to just simply pull out a custom post type and order it by name - but the ordering isn't working and I'm not sure why not.

It's simply listing the posts in the order they appear in the WP admin.

Any thoughts on why my ordering isn't kicking in? It finds the correct post type and number of posts I specify - just the ordering doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Simon - Do you have any plugins that might be modifying the order queries? That would be the first place I'd look... Please update your question to list the plugins you are using.

Comment: Paste some of the output you get,so we can see what you are getting.

Comment: @Simon Also add this right after your `new WP_Query(...)` line to see what the SQL query looks like, and post that:  `echo $related_projects->request; exit;`

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding interferance from plugins by passing in the `suppress_filters` parameter. Eg. `suppress_filters => true` this will bypass any filters plugins are performing on the query... ;)

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't `get_posts()` preferred for custom loops?

Comment: @tnorthcutt - I think you are confusing with `query_posts()`. `get_posts()` calls `WP_Query()` so I always just use `WP_Query()`. But `query_posts()` is not really great for custom loops.

Comment: @t31os - Good suggestion!

Comment: @tnorthcutt `get_posts()` is not really requirement - any approach will do, as long as it isn't `query_posts()`. Using `WP_Query` is closer to Loop structure and so easier if you need to use template tags. `get_posts()` is better if you just need to do something with array of posts.

Comment: @Mike - I was surprised noone had mentioned it already, i'd consider it an easy and suitable fix, handy parameter.. :)

Comment: @t31os - I knew about it, I just never think to use it. Don't know why...

Comment: @MikeSchinkel you're right, I was confusing it with `query_posts()`. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tnorthcutt - n/p. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yep - I'm stupid.

Post Types Order plugin has an option (set by default) which overrides any ordering done in queries.  Turn that off and the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly what you fixed so that others with the same problem can benefit?

Comment: Wow, this just saved me a long time (well I already spent a long time..). Here's a screenshot of what to uncheck in Settings > Post type order: http://i.imgur.com/lKWwXQq.png

Comment: adding  `'ignore_custom_sort' => true` to your query parameters fixes the problem also

Answer (score 0):

into the file category.php use for example

```
sort_query_posts_by('title', 'desc');
```

or use ID, date  etc. (see the function below) before loop and insert the function below

```
if (! function_exists('sort_query_posts_by'))
{
    function sort_query_posts_by($order_by, $order = 'asc')
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $order_by = strtolower($order_by);
        $order    = strtolower($order);

        if ($order_by == 'rand') {
            shuffle($wp_query->posts);
            return;
        }

        if ($order_by == 'none') {
            $order_by = 'id';
            $order = 'asc';
        }

        $props = array(
            'author'        => 'return sqp_compare_by_number($o1->post_author, $o2->post_author, '.$order.');',
            'comment_count' => 'return sqp_compare_by_number($o1->comment_count, $o2->comment_count, '.$order.');',
            'date'          => 'return sqp_compare_by_number(strtotime($o1->post_date), strtotime($o2->post_date), '.$order.');',
            'id'            => 'return sqp_compare_by_number($o1->ID, $o2->ID, '.$order.');',
            'menu_order'    => 'return sqp_compare_by_number($o1->menu_order, $o2->menu_order, '.$order.');',
            'modified'      => 'return sqp_compare_by_number(strtotime($o1->post_modified), strtotime($o2->post_modified), '.$order.');',
            'parent'        => 'return sqp_compare_by_number($o1->post_parent, $o2->post_parent, '.$order.');',
            'title'         => 'return sqp_compare_by_string($o1->post_title, $o2->post_title, '.$order.');'
        );

        usort($wp_query->posts, create_function('$o1, $o2', $props[$order_by]));
    }

    function sqp_compare_by_number($n1, $n2, $order)
    {
        $n1 = (int) $n1;
        $n2 = (int) $n2;
        $v  = $n1 > $n2 ? 1 : ($n1 < $n2 ? -1 : 0);
        return ($order == 'desc') ? $v * -1 : $v;
    }

    function sqp_compare_by_string($s1, $s2, $order)
    {
        $v = strnatcasecmp($s1, $s2);
        return ($order == 'desc') ? $v * -1 : $v;
    }
}
```